# TypeError at /edit/ __init__() got multiple values for argument 'data'

Tags: django

I am trying to update user profile in Django 2.1 and Python 3.6.5 but am running into this error.

> TypeError at /edit/
>   **init**() got multiple values for argument 'data'

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from . forms import LoginForm, UserRegistrationForm, UserEditForm, ProfileEditForm
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from . models import Profile
from django.contrib import messages


@login_required()
def edit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user, data=request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(request.user.profile, data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Profile Updated Successfully!')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Error Updating Profile!')
    else:
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    return render(request, 'account/edit.html', {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form})
```

edit.html

```
{% extends 'account/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Edit Account{% endblock %}

{% block content%}
    <h1>Edit Your Account:</h1>
    <form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ user_form.as_p }}
    {{ profile_form.as_p }}

    <p><input type="submit" value="Update"> </p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please show your form classes and the full traceback. But are you sure you didn't mean `ProfileEditForm(insurance=request.user.profile, data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)`?

Comment: Thanks Daniel Roseman! I had missed that: ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile, data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)    It now works fine. Best Regards!